# How can I achieve SMOOTH movement of canvas item in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to play around with keyboard driven events in Tkinter so that I can move an object around a canvas widget. Up, Down, Left and Right work OK but when I try to program two keys together the movement is not a smooth diagonal motion. Furthermore, whenever a key is hit, the object moves, then there is a slight delay, and then it moves smoothly.
How can I achieve smooth movement THE MOMENT a key is pressed and how can I achieve a smooth diagonal motion?

This is the code so far:

```
from tkinter import *

x = 10
y = 10
a = 100
b = 100

def change_coord(event):
        if event.keysym == 'Up':
            canvas1.move(rect, 0,-5)
        if event.keysym == 'Up' and 'Right':
            canvas1.move(rect, 5,-5)
        if event.keysym == 'Up' and 'Left':
            canvas1.move(rect, -5,-5)
        if event.keysym == 'Down':
            canvas1.move(rect, 0,5)
        if event.keysym == 'Down' and 'Right':
            canvas1.move(rect, 5,5)
        if event.keysym == 'Down' and 'Left':
            canvas1.move(rect, -5,5)
        if event.keysym == 'Right':
            canvas1.move(rect, 5,0)
        if event.keysym == 'Left':
            canvas1.move(rect, -5,0)

window = Tk()
window.geometry("400x200")

#canvas and drawing
canvas1=Canvas(window, height = 200, width = 400)
canvas1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
coord = [x, y, a, b]
rect = canvas1.create_rectangle(*coord, outline="#fb0", fill="#fb0")

#capturing keyboard inputs and assigning to function
window.bind_all('<Up>', change_coord)
window.bind_all('<Down>', change_coord)
window.bind_all('<Left>', change_coord)
window.bind_all('<Right>', change_coord)
window.mainloop()
```

Many thanks!

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all your suggestions. I have been trying to implement an animation loop to work around the slight delay after hitting an arrow key but am now stuck. My NEW code is shown below but running the program doesn't result in the canvas item moving. Firstly, is the idea for the animation loop correct and secondly where do I call the 'move' function to get the item moving. Please help - thanks!

```
from tkinter import *

x = 10
y = 10
a = 100
b = 100
direction = None

def move():
    global x_vel
    global y_vel
    global direction
    if direction is not None:
        canvas1.move(rect, x_vel,y_vel)
        after(33,move)

def on_keypress(event):
    global direction
    global x_vel
    global y_vel
    if event.keysym == "Left":
        direction == "left"
        x_vel = -5
        y_vel = 0
    if event.keysym == "Right":
        direction == "right"
        x_vel = 5
        y_vel = 0
    if event.keysym == "Down":
        direction == "down"
        x_vel = 0
        y_vel = 5
    if event.keysym == "Up":
        direction == "up"
        x_vel = 0
        y_vel = -5

def on_keyrelease(event):
    global direction
    direction = None


window = Tk()
window.geometry("400x200")

#canvas and drawing
canvas1=Canvas(window, height = 200, width = 400)
canvas1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
coord = [x, y, a, b]
rect = canvas1.create_rectangle(*coord, outline="#fb0", fill="#fb0")

#capturing keyboard inputs and assigning to function
window.bind_all('<KeyPress>', on_keypress)
window.bind_all('<KeyRelease>', on_keyrelease)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Create variables `velocity_x` and `velocity_y`, which dictate how far the rect should move each frame. Keydown and keyup events should modify velocity, not position. By the way, `event.keysym == 'Down' and 'Right'` isn't doing what you think it's doing; `a == b and c` is equivalent to `(a == b) and c`, not `a == (b and c)` or `a == (b + c)`.

Comment: The delay between the first action and the "smooth" moves is probably a keyboard driver related issue. When you hit a key, the driver wait a while before flooding the key event related to that key. This parameter is called *Repeat Delay* on windows and  *Keyboard delay* on Linux. You can try to alter this values, but this could hinter the usability of the keyboard for other applications. The usual workaround is to trigger a looping timer on KeyPress, and stop it on KeyRelease.

Comment: Thanks guys. Kevin,kicking myself about my schoolboy error regarding the use of AND! I'm an idiot. In terms of velocity not position, could you add an example to show what you mean because isn't the 5 and -5 values acting as a velocity anyway?, increasing or decreasing these values will change the speed of the object? Sorry if I am being dense. Thanks FabienAndre too. Appreciate it

Comment: FabienAndre, I'm being cheeky here but could you provide an example of a looping time, logic makes perfect sense but struggling to implement correctly. I've added a while loop on press which breaks on release but my program keeps locking up. Sorry and thanks in advance.

Comment: No infinite while loops, please. You don't have the ability to receive new events until you leave the event handler, so that'll never return.

Answer (score 3):

Binding to basic keys is the wrong way to do this. Instead, bind to key down and key release, and use that to create a dictionary of pressed keys. Every N ms, run a function that uses that dictionary to determine how to move the object. (I'm uncertain if a Tkinter timer has the quality needed to do this right.)

Be sure to clear the dictionary if the program loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

1. Inside the if statements inside on_keypress() function, you were using == operator instead of = operator for setting the directions.
2. You were not calling the move() function after setting a direction inside on_keypress() function

Here is your code edited and working.

Note: Thank you so much for the code. I was looking for something like this and you saved me a lot of time. I edited yours and came here to give it to you so we all have it fixed

```
from tkinter import *

x = 10
y = 10
a = 100
b = 100
direction = None

def move():
    global x_vel
    global y_vel
    global direction
    if direction is not None:
        canvas1.move(rect, x_vel,y_vel)
        after(33,move)

def on_keypress(event):
    global direction
    global x_vel
    global y_vel
    if event.keysym == "Left":
        direction = "left"
        x_vel = -5
        y_vel = 0
    if event.keysym == "Right":
        direction = "right"
        x_vel = 5
        y_vel = 0
    if event.keysym == "Down":
        direction = "down"
        x_vel = 0
        y_vel = 5
    if event.keysym == "Up":
        direction = "up"
        x_vel = 0
        y_vel = -5
    
    move()

def on_keyrelease(event):
    global direction
    direction = None


window = Tk()
window.geometry("400x200")

#canvas and drawing
canvas1=Canvas(window, height = 200, width = 400)
canvas1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
coord = [x, y, a, b]
rect = canvas1.create_rectangle(*coord, outline="#fb0", fill="#fb0")

#capturing keyboard inputs and assigning to function
window.bind_all('<KeyPress>', on_keypress)
window.bind_all('<KeyRelease>', on_keyrelease)
window.mainloop()
```